# cmd /C command won't execute powershell script in the background

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I tried running the command:

```
start /B cmd /C " powershell "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "link here" -OutFile "%USERPROFILE%\Contacts\file.exe""&&start %USERPROFILE%\Contacts\file.exe"&& exit
```

But for some reason it executes the powershell script in the same window. So when I run this command it show me download bytes and after that process is finished and the file is opened then cmd can close. But I want to run that whole script in the background so I just open cmd run this command and it immediately closes and runs the command in the background.

Comment: `start /?` says about `/B` switch: *Start application **without creating a new window**…*.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do. I want it to create a new cmd window thats invisible and close the current one. And in the newly opened invisible window I want to execute a powershell script to download a file and then open it.

Comment: To piggyback off JosefZ's comment, you seemed confused on why it's staying in the same window when you're specfying `/B`. If you're looking to execute it as "*invisible*", the [PowerShell.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1) *cli* allows for an option of `hidden`. So there's no need to call `cmd.exe` again when you can use `PowerShell.exe -WindowStyle hidden`.

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. Sorry I didn't know how to explain it properly. Thank you Abraham Zinala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on the helpful comments and [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73695038/45375), using a simplified command that waits 2 seconds and then launches Notepad:

```
powershell -WindowStyle Hidden "Start-Sleep 2; Start-Process Notepad.exe" & exit
```

- Given that you want to close the *current* window and launch the PowerShell command *invisibly*, there is *no* need for using `cmd.exe`'s internal `start` command.

  - As an aside:

    - As pointed out, `start /B` by design launches the given executable in the *current* window.
    - If you were to omit `/B` but still use `start`, `powershell.exe` would *invariably* launch *visibly* first, and `-WindowStyle Hidden` would only take effect *afterwards*, resulting in a brief flashing of the window - this is a long-standing problem that may get fixed in a future edition of [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the modern, cross-platform successor to *Windows PowerShell* - see [GitHub issue #3028](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3028).
- The above invokes `powershell.exe` *synchronously*, which means that it will run in the *current* `cmd.exe` window, but - due to `-WindowStyle Hidden` - then *hides* the current window.

  - That is, the current window is virtually *instantly* hidden, but the `cmd.exe` session lives on; once the `powershell.exe` call has completed, however, `& exit` ensures that the `cmd.exe` session too is exited.